# select_tag rails 3 wrong number of arguments error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

I have this select_tag using Rails 3

```
<%= select_tag :area_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@areas.sort_by(&:name)), {:onChange => remote_function(:with => "'filter_by='+value", :url =>{ :controller=>"encoder/members", :action=>"filter_schools" } ) } %>
```

But I kept on getting the error "wrong number of arguments (1 for 3)." What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is on [`options_from_collection_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select), which requires at least 3 parameters.